# Regex - Replace All characters that are not part of a given word

Tags: regex

I have two strings:

```
MyDatabase_DEV

MyDatabase
```

I want to match all characters except DEV.

The regex I have is `[^(DEV)]` Which isn't quite right as that also matches the 'D' in 'Database'

Therefore in the first example, the matched characters should be `MyDatabase_` and the second example should be `MyDatabase`

What would the regex be for what I need?

Comment: *"I want to replace all characters except DEV"*  Replace with what?

Comment: updated question, I will do the replace in my application, I want to match all characters except DEV

Comment: Will work for ur case [`^(?(?=.*DEV).*(DEV).*|.*())`](https://regex101.com/r/gL9pxZ/1) but not everytime

Comment: `s=s.Replace("DEV","")`. No need to match text other than, remove what you do not need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement goes, although it doesn't look good, but this meets your criteria:

```
[^e]v|[^d]ev|d(?!ev)|de(?!v)|[^d]e(?=v)|e(?!v)|[^dev]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2SB0rX/1)

**p.s**: use the  **i** flag to make it case insensitive